# Can we use these SSG WSG APIs within Wordpress/Learndash?

Tags: ssg

Can we use these SSG WSG APIs within Wordpress/Learndash?

https://developer.ssg-wsg.sg/webapp/docs/product/4ZCqa7uABJeR6vtKUjsxyx/group/5QgnbY9GvH7KzcemkGY47V#

Answer (score 0):

Do read the Get Started Guides (https://developer.ssg-wsg.sg/webapp/guides) on how to kickstart the app development with the APIs and within your own application/website.

Unfortunately I am not entirely sure how much customization you can do with Learndash, but as far as SSG-WSG APIs are concerned, you should at least be able to call the APIs according to the MTLS or oAuth requirements stated in the App Development guide: https://developer.ssg-wsg.sg/webapp/guides/6gvz7gEnwU2dSIKPrTcXnq

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments Ying